# Removing logo from a very selected photo from multiple photos after a purchasing IAP using consumable model IAP iOS

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have collection of pictures with logo attached showing in my home screen. **I want user to remove logo from a particular picture if user likes the photo after purchasing IAP.** But apple want me use non-consumable model remove logo from all the pictures one time. But that's not my case. **I want user to remove logo from a very selected picture one by one from every picture.**

Comment: How your pictures coming on the home screen? is it API call?

Comment: yes from api call.

Answer (score 0):

This one can be the option to deal with the situation.

You can ask your backend guy to gives you both picture(one is with logo and one is original)in the response of API

Now you have to identify from the response which item(s) user had purchased. 
Based on that…

Show the original picture for the purchased item from the response and picture with a logo for the non purchased item.

Comment: i have problem while purchasing the product apple want me to use non-consumable one time payment for all the pictures. But i want to use consumable one by one remove logo from a picture

Comment: Think about how you will manage consumable with each picture from In-app purchase configure in the app store?